# Shadows interferes

Tags: html, css

I got 2 elements in my header. Repeated horizontally strip and the logo. My problem is that logo's shadow interferes with stripe's shadow.

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: url('../images/header_bg.png') repeat-x;
  color: #fff;
}
#logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 377px;
  height: 145px;
  background: url('../images/logo.png');  
}
```

[image: my site]
[image: logo]
[image: header_bg]

Comment: Can you also attach both images separately? It is hard to see what's going on with only the result.

Comment: Try setting the z-index of header to 1, and the logo to 0....not sure if it'll work, but worth a shot.

Comment: @MathieuImbert, I uploaded them.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson, doesn't work. But thanks for try.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it. I covered logo with white box and set logo's z-index to 9999.